# fade in / fade out in images in text/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The attached images are the  within html and a text/javascript i've implemented within the same index.html file so the screen loops through an array of three images. Is there any way I could add a fade-in/fade-out action, considering the code i've written here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnxqZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXnUY.png)

Comment: Code as images again.

Comment: Code must be posted as *text* here - we know you are using StackOverflow by googling an error and finding a solution. Often times the source code makes a big difference for finding a similar problem. Please help others by updating your question.